# How can I get Magento add to cart ajax push the right url and add the product to cart?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, magento

I am implementing an ajax add to cart on a Magento site.

Currently the right url to the product gets added in the form a tag and when I add to cart it works but I want this to post with ajax. The cart uses an `<a>` in the form that stores a url to a product through Magento's data template setup which can only be used as an `<a>` because of Magento's limitations.

The markup for this is as follows:

```
<form class="js-update-product" id="product_addtocart_form" action="">
                                <div class="colour-guide-link buying-options condensed-bold group">
                                    <span>Colour &amp; Size</span>
                                    (<span class="icon-question-sign"></span> <a href="#">guide</a>)
                                </div>

                                <div class="buying-options">
                                <? for ($i=0; $i < count($available_colors); $i++) { ?>
                                <a class="js-color-toggle button" href="#" data-color="<?= $available_colors[$i] ?>">
                                    <?= $available_colors[$i] ?>
                                </a>
                                <? } ?>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="size-options buying-options group">
                                <? foreach ($all_sizes as $size) { ?>
                                <span class="radio-size">
                                    <input type="radio" class="size-option" value="<? echo $size ?>" name="size" />
                                    <label class="number"><? echo $size ?></label>
                                </span>
                                <? } ?>                                
                                </div>
                                <!-- <button type="submit" class="buy-button buying-options"></button> -->                 
                                <a href="#" class="buy-button buying-options js-add-to-cart button" data-products-in-cart="<?= $products_in_cart ?>">
                                <span class="label">Add to Bag</span>
                                    <span class="spinner"></span>
                                    Add to bag
                                </a>
                                <div class="adding-msg">
                                    Adding to bag...
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Here is my code for the ajax that posts the form which is causing me issues.

The ajax:

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productAddToCartForm.submit = function (button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;
        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }
        var e = null;
        // Start of our new ajax code
        if (!url) {
            url = jQuery('.js-update-product').attr('action');
        }
        url = url.replace("checkout/cart", "ajax/index"); // New Code
        var data = jQuery('.js-update-product').serialize();
        data += '&isAjax=1';
        jQuery('#ajax_loader').show();
        try {
            jQuery.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  dataType: 'json',
                  type : 'post',
                  data: data,
                  success: function(data){
                      jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
                          //alert(data.status + ": " + data.message);
                          if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
                              jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                          }
                          if(jQuery('.header .links')){
                              jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                          }
                  }
            });
        } catch (e) {
        }
        // End of our new ajax code
        this.form.action = oldUrl;

        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);

productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Ideally what I would like is the ajax js to find the url in the `<a href="">` that is being clicked and use that to post as the url in the ajax. What I am struggling to get right is it finding the url in the form  and getting that into the post url.

Is this possible with the script as it is set up now but with a few tweaks?

Answer (score 0):

You replace ajax function or modify by below code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    //dataType: 'json',
    type : 'post',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
        //console.log(url);
        if (jQuery('#gd_total')) {
            jQuery("#gd_total").html( jQuery(data).find('#gd_total'));
        }

        if(jQuery('#itemC')){
          jQuery("#itemC").html( jQuery(data).find('#itemC'));
        }
    }
});
```